# How to get String from Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, classcastexception, spannablestring

I wrote some code to get text from the EditView, put it in the Intent Extras and set it in a TextView on other Activity.

Here is my code from the sending Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyLayoutActivity.this, LayoutForOneActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CaptionOne", String.valueOf(txt_caption1.getText()));
startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the code from my receiving Activity

```
Intent intent1 = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent1.getExtras();

if (bundle != null) {
    caption = bundle.getString("CaptionOne");
}
```

If try to run this code I get the ClassCastException looking like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast 
to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
intent.putExtra("CaptionOne", txt_caption1.getText().toString);
```

instead of

```
intent.putExtra("CaptionOne", String.valueOf(txt_caption1.getText()));
```

and also datatype of `caption` should be String

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String Data = i.getStringExtra("Data");
```

Comment: 1) `Data` is not the name of the extra. 2) This code is no different than getting the Bundle first.