# convert intent to string Android

Tags: android, string, android-intent, printing

I have a method with an intent. Depending on the user's selection a different local html file will load in the webview. How can I convert the intent to string for loadUrl to work? My goal is to print the html page displayed in the webview.

```
    public void onSaveDataClicked(View reLayout){

    final WebView webview;
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WriteJsJson();
    Activity context;

    context = _activity.get();
    Intent fire = new Intent(context, WebviewActivity.class);
    switch (_reportType) {
        case 1 :
            fire.putExtra("target", "daily"); // Parameters
        case 2 :
            fire.putExtra("target", "week");
        case 3 :
            fire.putExtra("target", "month");
    }
    startActivity(fire); doWebViewPrint(); }



    private void doWebViewPrint() {
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
            createWebPrintJob(webview);
            mWebView = null;
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("need a string");
    mWebView = webview;
}
```

Comment: try String url=getIntent().getStringExtra("yourkey");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get String from Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260154/how-to-get-string-from-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your webActivity class get the string value of your Url

```
String url =  getIntent().getStringExtra("target");
 private void doWebViewPrint() {
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
            createWebPrintJob(webview);
            mWebView = null;
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(url);
    mWebView = webview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the WebviewActivity use

String url=getIntent().getStringExtra("target");

webview.loadUrl(url);

Hope it helps.